# How is phosphorus-32 produced?

Tags: isotope, radioactivity

I'm doing an assignment where I have to research a radioisotope of my choice. I decided to do phosphorus-32 and my assignment requires me to explain how the isotope is made. There is very minimal information on the production of phosphorus-32 so I'm in a little trouble.

A brief explanation would be much appreciated!

Comment: Start here: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmogenic_nuclide.

Comment: The Evaluated Nuclear Structure Data File site at the National Nuclear Data Center (nndc.bnl.gov) has data on about a dozen different nuclear reactions that result in 32P. Or the Nuclear Data Sheet at https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0090375211000767

Answer (score 3):

The most important nuclear reactions for the generation of anthropogenic P-32 are
Cl-35 (n, α) P-32,
S-32 (n, p) P-32, and
P-31 (n, γ) P-32.
Since especially chloride, sulfate, and phosphate can occur as impurities in water, typical P-32 activity concentrations in the reactor coolant of light water reactors are in the range of several kBq per litre. (Sources for impurities in the reactor water of BWR’s can be leaking condensers; in the primary coolant of PWR’s, phosphorous compounds in the added boric acid. Sulfate might also be released from cation exchange resins.)

In the laboratory, P-32 can be produced (even as an experiment with students) using the S-32 (n, p) P-32 reaction with fast neutrons. A sample of pressed elemental sulfur is placed close to a neutron source for several days. After that, the sulfur is washed with boiling water. The conversion of the α-sulfur allotrope to β-sulfur at 95.3 °C helps to release the phosphorous compounds from the solid sulfur matrix to the water. Thus, the resulting P-32 solution can be made carrier-free.